# Convert polygons into spatial points to use R "redlistr" package

Tags: r, geometry-conversion, polygon-to-point

I want to use the the `makeEOO` function from the [redlistr package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/redlistr/versions/1.0.1/topics/makeEOO) to calculate the Extent of Occurrence of 2 species ("binomial" A and B),  starting from a shapefile with the corresponding distribution maps in form of polygons. To use the function, I need to convert the polygons into points.
[Here the starting shapefile](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iOdd9L4FaYJuKzg56pPBu9vHYneAA9Ea?usp=sharing).

I am using the `sf` package to import the shapefile

```
 library(sf)    
 dummy <- st_read(dsn = "Calculate_EOO_dummy/dummy_maps_dissolved.shp")
 plot(dummy)
```

[image]

I converted the polygons into multipoint features, and the multipoints into points

```
multi.p <- st_cast(dummy.diss, "MULTIPOINT")
my.points <- multi.p %>%  group_by(binomial) %>% st_cast("POINT")
plot(my.points)
my.points
```

[image]

```
> my.points
Simple feature collection with 33 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -0.9471488 ymin: -0.9276773 xmax: 1.155772 ymax: 0.8080668
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# A tibble: 33 x 2
# Groups:   binomial [2]
   binomial                 geometry
   <fct>                 <POINT [°]>
 1 A          (-0.5855355 0.7913769)
 2 A          (-0.5771905 0.7774687)
 3 A          (-0.2267038 0.5771905)
 4 A         (-0.3936022 0.05702364)
 5 A         (-0.1098748 -0.1015299)
 6 A          (0.02642559 -0.340751)
 7 A        (-0.02920723 -0.4464534)
 8 A         (-0.3824757 -0.4297636)
 9 A         (-0.8553547 -0.2878999)
10 A         (-0.9471488 -0.1182197)
# ... with 23 more rows
```

However, if I try to call the `makeEOO` function with my.points, I get an error:

```
eoo <- my.points %>% group_by(binomial) %>% makeEOO()
```

**Error in makeEOO(my.points) : trying to get slot "coords" from an object (class "sf") that is not an S4 object.**

How could I convert such polygons (separately for each species A and B) into points to use `makeEOO`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redlistr` package depends on the `sp` package, and not on `sf`, there is [an open issue on the package's GitHub about supporting `sf`](https://github.com/red-list-ecosystem/redlistr/issues/9), but has not been addressed yet. So what you should do is add a step where you convert your `sf` object into a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object instead. Be careful though, you cannot apply `dplyr` verbs to `sp` objects. So you will probably need to split your data before using the `makeEOO()` function. This is how I would do it:

```
my.points.A <- my.points %>% filter(binomial == 'A') %>% as('Spatial')
my.points.B <- my.points %>% filter(binomial == 'B') %>% as('Spatial')
eoo.A <- my.points.A %>% makeEOO()
eoo.B <- my.points.A %>% makeEOO()
```